# Given a 2D array, convert to Z-Order

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

Having trouble wrapping my head around this conversion. I want to recursively convert a 2D NxN matrix into its z-order version.

For example given array:

```
[ 1  2 ]
[ 3  4 ]
```

The Z-order is

```
[ 1 2 3 4]
```

What are the steps recursively for the z-order conversion?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. Could you clarify?

Comment: @luiscubal what do you find unclear exactly?

Comment: do you want to create a new array for the Z vector ?

Comment: What 'z-order' in this context means, for instance and why being 'recursive' matters.

Comment: The explanation below gave some insight as to how z-order is implicit.
Z-order in this case refers to the order in which a matrix is traveled.

Comment: But why is recursion important in your case?

Comment: To parallelize it, not too sure if it can be done though with the explanation below

Comment: @Derptacos At 2x2, any paralelization you attempt to do will cause the program to run slower. And, either way, I don't see how making it recursive would help with that. If anything, it would make it harder, since tools such as OpenMP work perfectly with loops, but fail with recursion.

Answer (score 4):

The recursive way is simple:

- visit top-left
- visit top-right
- visit bottom-left
- visit bottom-right

In code

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename M, typename CBACK>
void zorder(const M& m, int y0, int x0, int size,
            CBACK cback)
{
    if (size == 1) {
        // Base case, just one cell
        cback(m[y0][x0]);
    } else {
        // Recurse in Z-order
        int h = size/2;
        zorder(m, y0,   x0,   h, cback); // top-left
        zorder(m, y0,   x0+h, h, cback); // top-right
        zorder(m, y0+h, x0,   h, cback); // bottom-left
        zorder(m, y0+h, x0+h, h, cback); // bottom-right
    }
}

void print(int x) {
    std::cout << x << " ";
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int x[][4] = {{ 1,  2,  3,  4},
                  { 5,  6,  7,  8},
                  { 9, 10, 11, 12},
                  {13, 14, 15, 16}};
    zorder(x, 0, 0, 4, print);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program is

```
1 2 5 6 3 4 7 8 9 10 13 14 11 12 15 16
```

Note that there is also another non-recursive approach: to visit the elements in z-order you can just iterate over a counter and take odd-bits as y and even-bits as x (counting bits from 0):

```
int zorder_x_of(int index) {
    int x = 0;
    for (int b=0,k=0; (1<<b) <= index; b+=2,k++) {
        x += ((index & (1<<b)) != 0) << k;
    }
    return x;
}

int zorder_y_of(int index) {
    return zorder_x_of(index>>1);
}

template<typename M, typename CBACK>
void zorder2(const M& m, int size, CBACK cback)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size*size; i++) {
        cback(m[zorder_y_of(i)][zorder_x_of(i)]);
    }
}
```

Note:

In the above code samples I created a function that accepts a "callback" (named `cback`) that is something that will be called with the elements of the matrix, one at a time, in z-order.

To allow using both as matrix and as callback anything that supports double `[]` indexing and anything that can be called I used a C++ template.

In the main program as matrix I've used a bi-dimensional array of integers and a function, but the code would have compiled even for example with an `std::vector< std::vector< double > >` as matrix and an object instance of a class providing `operator()(double)` as callback.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Trying to under stand the use of CBACK if you don't mind elaborating.

Comment: @Derptacos: I've added an explanation on `cback` parameter but of course a single SO answer is not the correct place to explain C++ template metaprogramming. If you don't know anything about it I'd suggest to investigate a bit on the topic because templates can be a powerful weapon in a few cases. Be warned however that there is a serious risk of being dragged in a template fetishism where template are abused far beyond common sense limits and where even nonsenses like boost.spirit seem reasonable tools.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D matrix behaves internally as an 1D array i.e. it is already in "Z order".

Just iterate across the pointer that points to the first element up to `NxM` where `N` is the number of columns and `M` the number of rows.

example:

```
int arr[2][2] = {{2,4},{3,5}};
for (int i=0; i<2 * 2; ++i){
    std::cout << *(&arr[0][0] + i);  // or *(arr + i)
}
```